# How to compare array elements one after another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

`let a = [33, 15, 67, 203450, 212]`

Above is the array that I am working with. I need to compare every previous element to the next one till the last element of the array. If the element is bigger than the one before it I add 2 into the "myNums". If the element is smaller than the one before it I add 1 into the "myNums". If the element equals the element before it I add 0 into the "myNums".

I made 3 functions to get me the sum of the digits I pushed into "myNums", but none of them works. So, how do I do this ?

Below are the functions I made to solve my problem.

```js
function b(cmp) {
    for (let c = 0; c < cmp.length; c++) {
        let A = cmp[c]
        let B = cmp[c + 1]
        let myNums = []
        if (A < B) {
            myNums.push(1)
        }
        else if (A > B) {
            myNums.push(2)
        }
        else {
            myNums.push(0)
        }
        let sum = 0
        console.log(myNums)
        for (let d = 0; d < myNums.length; d++) {
            sum += myNums[d];
        }
        return sum
    }
}
let d = b(a)
console.log(d)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function b(cmp) {
    while ((c = 0) && (c < cmp.length)) {
        let A = cmp[c]
        let B = cmp[c + 1]
        let myNums = []
        while ((A < B) || (A > B) || A == B) {
            if (A < B) {
                myNums.push(1)
            }
            else if (A > B) {
                myNums.push(2)
            }
            else {
                myNums.push(0)
            }
        }
        let sum = 0
        for (let d = 0; d < myNums.length; d++) {
            sum += myNums[d];
        }
        return sum
    }
    c++
}
let d = b(a)
console.log(d)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function b(cmp) {
    for (let c = 0; c < cmp.length; c++) {
        let A = cmp[c]
        let B = cmp[c + 1]
        let C = []
        let D = 0
        switch (B) {
            case (A < B):
                C.push(1)
            case (A > B):
                C.push(2)
            case (A == B):
                C.push(0)
        }
        for (let d = 0; d < C.length; d++) {
            D += C[d];
        }
        return C
    }
}
let e = b(a)
console.log(e)
```

They gave me either 0 or 1 or an empty array in the console.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please elaborate what exactly you want to ask. After reading your question it seems like you got some assignment that you're not able to do and asking here for the solution.

Comment: What is `myNums`? Also, please add the desired output.

Comment: In all three versions, you have a `return` statement _inside_ the loop over the data - which means, it will only iterate _one_ time, before it gets exited. The part where you sum up the values in myNums/C and return that sum, of course belongs _after_ the loop over the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

this code will compare the array
loop the element and check each one

```js
function compareElements(cmp) {
    let myNums = [];  

    for (let c = 0; c < cmp.length - 1; c++) {  // loop until the second last element
        let A = cmp[c];
        let B = cmp[c + 1];

        if (A < B) {
            myNums.push(2);  //bigger
        } else if (A > B) {
            myNums.push(1);  //smaller
        } else {
            myNums.push(0);  
        }
    }

    let sum = 0;
    for (let d = 0; d < myNums.length; d++) {
        sum += myNums[d];  // total
    }

    return sum;  
}

let a = [33, 15, 67, 203450, 212];
let result = compareElements(a);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment you return inside the loop thus breaking it. Just return in the end of the function.

**BUT** since you return a sum of your comparison you don't need collect the comparison values in an intermediate array, just sum them.

Also you could use the conditional operator for shortness instead of several `if`s. That's a common expression in comparison functions:

```js
function compareElements(cmp) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let c = 0; c < cmp.length - 1; c++) {  // loop until the second last element
        let A = cmp[c];
        let B = cmp[c + 1];
        sum += A < B ? 2 : A > B ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return sum;  
}

let a = [33, 15, 67, 203450, 212];
let result = compareElements(a);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not define any functions. Loop from the second array to the last to construct the `[0,1,2]` array. Then use the `Array#reduce` method to get the sum of the elements of the array.

```js
const a = [33, 15, 67, 203450, 212];
const myNums = [];

for (let i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
    const x = a[i], y = a[i-1];
    myNums.push( x === y ? 0 : x < y ? 1 : 2 );
}

console.log( myNums );

const sum = myNums.reduce((a,c) => a + c, 0);

console.log( sum );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sliche the array and map the result by taking the sign of the delta with adjustments.

```js
const
    array = [33, 15, 67, 203450, 212],
    result = array
        .slice(1)
        .map((v, i) => (1 + Math.sign(v - array[i]) || 3) - 1);

console.log(result);
```

A slightly better approach by taking an object for values.

```js
const
    values = { '-1': 2, 0: 0, 1: 1 },
    array = [33, 15, 67, 203450, 212],
    result = array
        .slice(1)
        .map((v, i) => values[Math.sign(v - array[i])]);

console.log(result);
```